# "The RelatedEnd with role name X has already been loaded" error message

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am strugling to understand why the query is retuning this error when I perform the following statement:

```
SelectFor(x => x.Id == id, true, false, "Scope.Hiring.Scopes")
```

The string in the above statement are the entities to include.

**SelectFor Method:**

```
public virtual TEntity SelectFor(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, bool noTracking = true, bool selectInactiveItems = false, params string[] entitiesToLoad)
        {
            var query = this.LoadRelatedEntities(this.transaction.Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable(), entitiesToLoad);
            query = query.Where(x => x.OwnerId == ownerId).Where(predicate);

            if (!selectInactiveItems)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Active);
            }

            if (noTracking)
            {
                query = query.AsNoTracking();
            }

            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

**Include Method**

```
protected IQueryable<TEntity> LoadRelatedEntities(IQueryable<TEntity> query, params string[] entitiesToLoad)
        {
            if (entitiesToLoad != null && entitiesToLoad.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var entityToLoad in entitiesToLoad)
                {
                    query = query.Include(entityToLoad);
                } 
            }

            return query;
        }
```

It seems quite easy thing to do, but it's taking my time and patience.

Comment: Hardly enough info. What are you selecting, what do the classes look like? Esp. show the entire LINQ statement in which you use `SelectFor`.

Comment: One possible reason could be if `Hiring.Scopes` is the inverse navigation property of `Scope.Hiring`. Try passing `"Scope.Hiring"` only.

Comment: GertArnold The entire LINQ is above, and the classes have the navigation property with the names correctly.

@IvanStoev if I do this separately it'll works, but I would like to understand why this is not working that way, just for understand.

Comment: Well, no, because it's not clear what `TEntity` you're querying. Anyway, I'm pretty sure what your issue is. See the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `AsNoTracking` in your query. Because of this, EF doesn't keep track of the entities it materializes. This means that when it fetches `Scope`s from the database it will create multiple objects for each "identical" scope. This definitely happens here because of the circular query pattern `Scope.Hiring.Scopes`.

However, EF *does* perform relationship fixup while building the object graph, i.e. it populates navigation properties with entities that are materialized so that f.e. each `Scope` object will have a `Hiring` reference. While doing this, I figure it tries to assign a duplicated `Scope` object to a `Hiring` object that already has this object.

Solution: remove the `AsNoTracking` or remove the circular query: `Scope.Hiring` instead of `Scope.Hiring.Scopes`.

Comment: I agree, I already knew it work without AsNoTracking, but I didn't know why, and that's why, Thank you.

Comment: FYI, in EF-core this has been improved. Even with `AsNoTracking`, EF-core will track entities while handling a query. It won't create duplicates and it will reuse references for relationship fixup. This is great, because EF6's behavior can cause very covert bugs and even compromised data.

Comment: Very nice to know.